# Command parameter in EventTrigger

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, mvvmcross, eventtrigger, commandparameter

I'm working on WinRT with MvmmCross v3 framework and [Windows.UI.Interactivity](https://github.com/jlaanstra/Windows.UI.Interactivity/).

I want a TextBox with an EventTrigger on the event TextChanged which launch a Command. And also, I want in CommandParameter the text of the textBox.

So I have this code

```
   <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction  Command="{Binding UpdateText}" CommandParameter="{Binding Text}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>


public ICommand UpdateText
{
    get
    {
        return new MvxCommand<object>((textSearch) =>
            {
                // code...
            });
    }
}
```

But my textSearch parameter equals to "{Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs}" with all of these properties NULL.

I Tried also to declare explicitly my ElementName in the binding like

```
CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=tes}
```

But it failed too.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share a repro project?

Comment: I will do it, as soon as possible

Comment: Here you can see the GitHub project https://github.com/podelo/WinRTEventTrigger

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you really need to handle `TextChanged` event? You could be notified of the changes by just binding to the `Text` property:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding TextValue, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

And then in the view model:

```
private string _textValue;
public string TextValue
{
    get
    {
        return _textValue;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_textValue == value)
            return;
        _textValue = value;
        OnTextChanged(value); // react to the changed value
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

There are two things you need to be aware of, if you want to get to the `Text` value from inside your `Command`:

**First**, you need to fix the `CommandParameter` binding. By using `{Binding Text}` you are actually trying to bind to a property in your view model, i.e. you would first need to bind the `TextBox.Text` property to the same view model property. As you've said in the comment, that's no good for you because you need the info on every change and not only on lost focus, so the value you get is not up to date enough.

The right approach would therefore be your second attempt, i.e. binding directly to the `TextBox` using the `ElementName` syntax. Unfortunately triggers are not a part of the visual tree therefore they don't get access to the XAML name scope (you can read more about it in [this blog post](http://julmar.com/blog/mark/?p=237)). You can work around that by using `NameScopeBinding` from [MVVMHelpers.Metro package](https://mvvmhelpers.codeplex.com/):

```
<Behaviors:NameScopeBinding x:Key="MyTextBox" 
                            Source="{Binding ElementName=MyTextBox}" />
```

Now you can make the `ElementName` binding work:

```
<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding UpdateText}" 
    CommandParameter="{Binding Source.Text, Source={StaticResource MyTextBox}}"/>
```

You still have the **second** problem. The `Text` value that you are binding to only updates on lost focus so you don't get the right value when handling `TextChanged` event. The solution is to bind to the `TextBox` itself:

```
<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding UpdateText}" 
    CommandParameter="{Binding Source, Source={StaticResource MyTextBox}}"/>
```

And then inside the command get the `Text` property directly from the `TextBox`:

```
private void OnUpdateText(object parameter)
{
    var value = ((TextBox) parameter).Text;
    // process the Text value as you need to.
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

To make the above code work with the view model being in a PCL, there a couple of approaches you could take.

The **simplest hack** would be to use reflection. Since it is available in PCL you could get to the `Text` property and read its value:

```
private void OnUpdateText(object parameter)
{
    var textProperty = textSearch.GetType().GetProperty("Text");
    var value = textProperty.GetValue(parameter, null) as string;
    // process the Text value as you need to.
}
```

A **cleaner solution** would be to put the WinRT specific code into a separate assembly abstracted via an interface. You would first create an interface in the PCL library:

```
public interface IUiService
{
    string GetTextBoxText(object textBox);
}
```

And modify view model to accept this interface in the constructor:

```
public ViewModel(IUiService uiService)
{
    _uiService = uiService;
}
```

In the command handler you would than use the method in the interface:

```
private void OnUpdateText(object parameter)
{
    var value = _uiService.GetTextBoxText(parameter);
    // process the Text value as you need to.
}
```

You would implement that interface in a WinRT library:

```
public class UiService : IUiService
{
    public string GetTextBoxText(object textBox)
    {
        var typedTextBox = textBox as TextBox;
        return typedTextBox.text;
    }
}
```

In the application you reference this library and pass the implementation to view model:

```
var viewModel = new ViewModel(new UiService);
```

My **favorite approach** is different: I'd create a `Behavior` exposing a `Text` property automatically updated every time `TextChanged` event is triggered:

```
public class TextChangedBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Text", 
        typeof(string), 
        typeof(TextChangedBehavior), 
        new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }


    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.TextChanged += OnTextChanged;
        Text = AssociatedObject.Text;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.TextChanged -= OnTextChanged;
    }

    private void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs textChangedEventArgs)
    {
        Text = AssociatedObject.Text;
    }
}
```

Now I could bind a `TextValue` property to this behavior and react to its change in the property setter as already suggested at the very beginning of this long answer:

```
<TextBox>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <b:TextChangedBehavior Text="{Binding TextValue, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I really need the TextChanged because with a simple binding we have to lost focus to throw the binding.
In my case it's to search some item in a big list, I really need to update my list every time my user enter a key.

Comment: @DevCrosser I updated my post by explaining your binding didn't work and showing to make it work as you need it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, it works with a simple project. But I use PCL core, so in my ViewModels I can't have the TextBox class.
In debug I see my parameter with the Text property wich works, but as I said I can't cast it in the code.
I tried to add Path=Text in the NameScopeBinding but when typing in my InputText the output is printing with one letter delay.

Comment: @DevCrosser I added a couple of suggestions to make everything work using PCL.

Comment: I was reluctant to add MVVMHelpers to my project just to try this, but it did work and I've got my CommandParameter referring to an element name. I used the common MVVMHelpers package, rather than the Win 8.1 specific, and your `CommandParameter="{Binding Source.Text, Source={StaticResource MyTextBox}}"`. My control name is `userControl` and I am getting a dependency property on it called `BumpAmount` so it was: `<Behaviors:NameScopeBinding x:Key="UserControl" Source="{Binding ElementName=userControl}" ` and `CommandParameter="{Binding Source.BumpAmount, Source={StaticResource UserControl}}`/